# What is the missing step here to insert random numbers into the array (c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to insert random numbers [1;100] into this array of 5 elements but so far I've been using only cin>> for inserting, when the user had to put something in. In this case I would like the random function to insert numbers, no user involved.

I show the code below because I am a beginner and the included pieces of codes are mostly what I can use and understand but on the other hand the whole code is useless because I don't know what is to connect with what. Where is rand()%100+1 to put?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int a[5];
    int r=rand()%100+1;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are only creating one random number and you are not putting that into an array

Comment: You probably should put the `rand()` statement into the 1st loop.

Comment: Unrelated, [give `<random>` a whirl](http://ideone.com/Lq0chX). it's the cat's whiskers.

Answer (score 1):

In your program you have 2 loops that both print out result. I suppose previously you had one loop that used cin to insert values, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cin<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

So you want to change from inserting with ci to inserting random number:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    a[i] = rand()%100+1
}
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not initializing the values of the array elements using the rand() function.

Your rand function should go inside the first 'for' loop.Something like the following will do the trick.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a[i] = rand()%100+1;
}
```